# After upgrading nodejs to 5.8.0 I can no longer use sudo npm

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I just did a nodejs update to 5.8.0 with the following commands

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

and now when i try to run "sudo npm [...]" to install a package I get this command line error

> /usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied

My password is correct and no other changes were made

Comment: I would recommend to do following. In your terminal run `which node` to find node executable. Then `ls -l /folder/where/node/is` (in my case it's /usr/local/bin) to see current permissions. Then you can try `sudo chmod +x node` if you don't have exec permission

Comment: install nvm and then use the stable version of node.

Comment: looks like something wrong with sudo. Can you check same using 'su' command under root user?

Comment: @alexey I get the same error using 'su'

Comment: @Molda When i run 'which node', i get "bash: /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory" this happens for any other command I type after "which". To add more info, if i type "sudo which node" i get this: "sudo: which: command not found" even though the command is clearly there.. strange.

Comment: why are you running 'wich node'? You should run 'which nodejs'.
Cay you try 'sudo chmod +X /usr/bin/env'?

Comment: @alexey Molda told me too. 'node' is the command, by the way. The chmod command didn't work unfortunately.